# Checkmarx, LDAP-Injection and ESAPI.encodeForLDAP

Tags: java, ldap, esapi, checkmarx

This Statement is rightfully flagged by Checkmarx as as possible LDAP_Injection.

```
String filter = "(&(objectclass=accessGroup)(member=cn=*)(dsApplicationName=" + application + "))";
```

With the ESAPI-Encoder, I would expect that this solves the Problem:

```
String saneApplication = org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder.getInstance().encodeForLDAP(application);
String filter = "(&(objectclass=accessGroup)(member=cn=*)(dsApplicationName=" + saneApplication + "))";
```

But Checkmarx still flags it as `LDAP_Injection`.

No idea how to solve this properly.

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 2):

You can override the functions used as a sanitizer in the query, using CxAudit.
E.g. have a project/corporate override for Find_LDAP_Sanitize(), and include (in addition to the original) the ESAPI functions - select the method calls, and add those to the original list.

P.S. already asked for that to be added into the default, but I have no idea when it will be :-)

P.P.S. OWASP ESAPI is pretty much being superseded by the OWASP Encoder project, however that doesn't really support LDAP encoding.
Long term, you may want to restructure your code to avoid any kind of concatenation.